# window.requestFeature not working in kindle fire and actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, kindle-fire

I am using a trick to avoid showing the `actionbar` while the application loads. Such trick works perfect in typical Android systems, but fail on Amazon Kindle Fires.

It involves **setting the `actionbar` to false** in the application theme, then re-enable it in onCreate:

theme:

```
 <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> 
 <item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item>
```

onCreate:

```
public void onCreate() {
    .
    .
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(resourceId);
}
```

The call to `requestFeature()` has to be made before the `setContentView()` -Android Spec-. 
This works fine for **normal Android devices**. However, on Kindle Fire HDX, this doesnt' work!

```
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

I have not added, as you see, the content myself before this call. I suspect Amazon's Android does something under the hood because their `actionbars` and system bars are totally different to Stock Android, and this breaks this functionality.

Any idea? As I suppose the answer is "don't use that trick", is it possible to declare themes in Manifest conditionally for different devices?

Comment: What's your reason for hidding the ActionBar while your application load?

Comment: just for aestethic reasons :)